# How to create this data base?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm a beginner in development. I'm breaking my head and I'm confused as to the problem below.

**an employee can be a programmer or analyst**

Programmer

- name
- sex
- age
- programming language

Analyst

- name
- sex
- age
- Project

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a row associated with each Employee that stores the Foreign key of whether the employee is an Analyst or a Programmer.

E.g.

```
Employee
 - id
 - Name
 - Sex
 - Age
 - Type_Id

Types
 - id
 - Type
```

Example Data:

```
Types
 - 1, Programmer
 - 2, Analyst

Employee
 - 1, "Sid", "Male", 25, 1
 - 2, "Sandra", "Female", 28, 2
```

With this approach, if more roles are added in future, you can just add it to master table `Types` and refer it from `Employee` Table.

Comment: and where i create programming language and Project?

Comment: You can use Postgres SQL scripts to create.  CREATE TABLE scripts with constraints should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreign keys.

So if you have an Employee table, you can connect them likes this:

```
Employee

id
name
sex
age

Programmer

employeeId

Analyst

employeeId
```

`EmployeeId` will refer to a row inside the Employee table with a matching `id` column

Comment: In Employee table, will I just have the id?

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: @Renato Benatti Edited my answer. Moved the name, age and sex to the Employee table. You can add additional analyst or programmer data into their table if necessary

Comment: Instead you can invert this.

Comment: I created a function table where you will have:
name, language and project. But if an employee is a programmer, for example, he will not have a project.